# Delete old question and post again?

Tags: discussion, questions

Is it OK to delete a question that didn't get much activity and post it again?

I've actually seen a user do this and gotten answer on third attempt.

Comment: @Shog9 the question this one allegedly a duplicate of does not address the issue of a user *deleting* a question only to repost it. The closest scenario handled there is someone reposting *while not deleting their earlier question*: close as duplicate. Fair enough. But when the earlier question has been deleted, this cannot happen. In my view, delete-repost is gaming the system (and annoying: I don't want to reread the same question). I used to close-vote with a custom reason but other users with c-v privileges objected, and so I've backed off. There does not seem to be a consensus.

Comment: @Louis still a dupe, just of a different question.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Now that question is about deleting a question that was marked as **duplicate** and all the answers stress that fact. My question is about simply deleting a unique question and posting again at a later time.

Comment: @laggingreflex I see, but the answer is the same: no, it's not OK. The proper way is what described in the [first dupe](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-do-i-get-attention-for-old-unanswered-questions?lq=1). So not sure there's a point reopening yet again.

Comment: @laggingreflex From what perspective are you asking? Are you asking "can I (should I) do it?" Or are you asking "how should we deal with a user that does it?" The duplicate that Shog9 (and one other user) suggested was (almost) answering the latter question. And that's also what I took you to be asking. However, Shadow Wizard is giving you links that answer the 1st. If what you want to know is just whether you can do it, then Shadow Wizard's links answer the question.

Comment: @Louis The latter one indeed. Like I said, I saw a user do it but couldn't find a question here that I could link them to that authoritatively say so. Frankly if I were doing it and got linked to those questions that this one is marked as dupe of, I would have still been unconvinced as they're not talking about the exact same situation as this question describes. Although now seeing as ShadowWizard's "not OK" comment stands as authoritative "answer" I guess it'll work..